# How do i call an integer from one method in another method?

Tags: java, string, class, methods, integer

I'm fairly new to programming with Java... but this has really got me stumped, I've searched for a while and I could not find a clear answer to what I was looking for... but let's say I have two methods

```
public static void program1 (String[] args) {
    Integer intMoney;
    intMoney = 500;
}

public static void program2 (String[] args) {
    String strYes;
    strYes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("type yes to subtract 100");
    if((strYes.equals("Yes") || (strYes.equals("yes")))) {
    /*((This is where I call the intMoney from program1) */ - 100;
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thats not yes!");
    }
}
```

And here is where I get really stuck.. say I have another method like program1, But how can I call on the `intMoney` value in program1 in another method?

Let's say I have a program and I want `intMoney` to be declared in a separate method so that when the Method program2 gets repeated the `intMoney` value wont change and it will be the same when the method is called on again.

Comment: dont mind the ; on the if statement, that was suppoed to be after the - 100

Comment: you can easily edit your post to correct your error. Most of us cringe on seeing stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your program is totally out of rules and regulation having so many mistakes:

1. intMoney has function scope.So, it cannot be called from outside the function **program1()**. You have to return value from this function to use in another function.
2. In your **if** you are checking 2 condition separated by || but both conditions are same.Use one please.

   ```
   public static int program1 () {
   Integer intMoney;
   intMoney = 500;
   return intMoney;
   }

   public static void program2 () {
   String strYes;
   strYes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("type yes to subtract 100");
   if((strYes.equals("Yes") || (strYes.equals("yes")))); {
   program1() - 100
   }else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thats not yes!");

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: If program1 returns an int...declare intMoney as int...why create an Integer for that??

Comment: there is a concept called autoboxing in which java will automatically convert Integer to int.By the way you can use int also.I just try to less modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can' access access the variable in program1 since it't scoped to the method. You should do something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static Integer intMoney;

    public static void program1(String[] args) {
        intMoney = 500;
    }

    public static void program2(String[] args) {
        String strYes;
        strYes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("type yes to subtract 100");
        if ((strYes.equals("Yes") || (strYes.equals("yes"))))
        {
            Integer i = intMoney;
            Integer x = i - 100;

        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thats not yes!");

        }
    }
}
```

Of course now you need to call program1 first in order for the variable to be set. You could also just initiate it like this `public static final Integer intMoney = 500`;

Also, what's with the String[] args parameters if you are not using them?

Comment: And shouldn't he be using an int variable instead of Integer?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels probably, not sure if he's doing anything causing boxing later?

Comment: I sincerely doubt it since his question is quite basic, and so the odds of him needing an Integer I'll wager is quite low. I'll bet he doesn't know the difference.